# Theoretical Probability

Tags: probability

Brady spun the arrow 100 times on the spinner. The arrow landed on the section "P" 18 times. How many more times should the arrow have landed on the section labeled "P" to match the theoretical probability?

Comment: Well, how many spots are on the spinner? How many choices do you have for the section? What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with? (As stated, the problem is incomplete.)

Comment: 4 congruent sections.

Comment: So how many times do you think it *should* land in the section $P$, if there are $4$ sections? Please share what you've tried: You'll get much better responses if you explain what exactly you're having trouble with, rather than just copying your problem statement here.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 equal spots, and 100 spins that each land on one spot

This means that each spot *should* have 100/4 land on it, or 25

Since only 18 did, it should have landed on it 25-18 times or 7 times more than it did.